# Impossible to get my bundle include even with 20 eth as priority fees

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, ether, wallets, flashbots

```
Bundle was not included in target block.
```

Hello everyone, I hope you're all doing well. I'm currently attempting to execute a SwapExactETHForTokens transaction on Uniswap V2 using EIP-1559. When I try to perform this transaction without Flashbots, everything works as expected. However, when I include the transaction in a bundle, I encounter issues and the transaction is not getting included. I'm testing all of this on a local fork of the Ethereum mainnet. Can anyone help me identify what I might be doing wrong? Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Who will receive and include the request on your fork?
If not included, there are most likely either no validators running mev boost being assigned to propose the next block, or your transaction(s) would fail, or it isn't profitable to include.
You could test your set up on Goerli, target several blocks as there aren't a ton of flashbots validators on testnet, send to goerli-flashbots end point and if valid should be included. Can use eth_callBundle to simulate and see if there is an issue with the bundle, or eth_call to check the individual transactions.

Comment: so it's not possible to simulate and send bundle in local fork mainnet?

Comment: Probably possible if you set up the validator instance and play both roles, but it's not something I have any experience with.

Comment: Thank you so much, i will try and see.

Comment: Much love, and good luck on your journey.